# How to identify all the scheduled queries in databricks SQLanalytics

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

How to identify all the scheduled queries in Databricks SQL Analytics?
One particular query is scheduled to run every one hour in our warehouse, which makes the cluster active all the time. We have to identify all the scheduled queries and trigger an email with list of all active triggers and scheduled queries, is there a way to do it?

I have tried to explore all the inbuild functions to check, if any of the existing inbuild functions gives this list but nothing worked so for. I'm able to get this details manually, if I go to the "Queries" tab.

Comment: Specify what you have tried to achieve this requirement.

Comment: Added few details.

Answer (score 0):

- It is not possible to query the list of saved or scheduled queries in Azure Databricks SQL.
- The `queries` tab that shows the required saved/scheduled queries which is workspace specific but it does not have an inbuild function in Databricks SQL itself.

[image]

- But there is no possible way to query this information. If you want to do it programmatically, you can use the REST API with python to get the list of queries.
- The [Queries, Dashboards, and Alerts API 2.0 - Azure Databricks - Databricks SQL | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/api/queries-dashboards) REST API will allow you to get the list of queries.
- You can use requests library to make an API call and achieve the requirement.